# Responsive Jquery/JS/CSS to collapse 2 divs into tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile

i have two div boxes side by side.  On mobile they dont work well, so I would like to make them responsive by actually collapsing into one box on top of the other, with a clickable tab to switch between the two boxes.

The base code for the two boxes:

**CSS :**

```
.form {
    color: white;
    max-width: 510px;
    height: 384px;
    text-align: center; 
}

.form-left {
    background-color: red;  
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.form-right {
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="form form-left">
            <h2 class="form-title">ONE</h2>
            <p class="artist">Some paragraph text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns">
        <div class="form form-right">
            <h2 class="form-title">TWO</h2>
            <p class="shopper">Some more paragraph text.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the very simple demo **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6jy6d0ge/)**.

When you resize the result pane, it should convert to the tabbed view.

I assume it can be done with jquery, but i wouldn't have a clue where to start ?

Comment: What do you mean by switch between the two boxes?

Comment: when it shrinks to mobile size, they will stick together, and become clickable tabs

Comment: Clickable tabs as in they direct you to another page when you click them?

Comment: tabs: https://jqueryui.com/tabs/